# Image quality expectation of 2K surveillance camera vs 4K iPhone? Resolution vs field of view

Tags: image-quality, resolution, iphone, field-of-view

I'd like to be able to identify licenses plates as they enter our cul-de-sac. My question is triggered by a comparison between an Arlo Pro 4 and an iPhone 12. The iPhone produces extremely high quality images and I think acceptable for what I want. The Pro 4 produces poor images. I believe my iPhone has a 4K camera vs the Pro 4, which is a 2K.

I realize I'm not showing an exactly fair comparison. Both of these pictures were downsized to 1024 width and I tried to disable compression; dropped colors to 256 using [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/).  Visually, these look similar to the originals, though.

Can you speculate on the reason for such poor image quality from the Pro 4? Would moving to a 4K model be sufficient? Because the field of view requirement is maybe 45 degrees am I thinking about things properly? For instance, would a 2K camera with a small field of view be better than the 2K with a ~150 degree field of view?

[image: Pro4]
[image: iPhone 12]

Comment: This simply isn't a security question at all in any way. This is a phone camera hardware question.

Comment: @schroeder, thanks for moving it to a better place

Comment: The iphone is not recording that quality video 24/7 over a network on a box is it? stored months at a time? Most consumer CCTV or even retail CCTV look rubbish compared to our phones because they are the result of the requirement to record continuously or for very long periods of time - so the quality of footage is compromised in order for it be recorded and stored more effectively. There are cameras that do record vehicle plates, and LE use them for example, but I don't think i've seen them in the consumer market, so the technology is there.

Comment: Surveillance cameras generally record *video*, not *still images*, which is what this community concentrates on. The site for *video* is [Video SE](https://video.stackexchange.com). The difference between your two examples is almost certainly due to the amount of compression used to store the video output from the Arlo more compactly compared to what appears to be a *still image* taken with your iPhone. (Rather than a frame grab?)

Comment: There is still something fishy. I took video just now with my iPhone 12. Its a bit lower quality than the still in my question. But it is close and far better than the security camera.  Maybe this is something I want but just can't have, but why can't the camera record as good as the iphone for 15 seconds before and after an event...ie always recording in hidef but then deleting anything older than 15 seconds which isn't part of an event?  Regardless, I guess the answer to my question is that the security camera compresses the image so I'm not really getting 2K or even close.

Comment: @RobertLugg I think the 2K/4K only describes the resolution you get in the end product, and it does not say anything about the resolution that the camera works with internally. The iphone is capable of 12MP, while the arlo can only do 4MP. Additionally the sensor on an arlo is physically smaller than on an iphone and perhaps the optics are not as sophisticated as on an iphone. So if your question is: how can I capture a licenseplate with my arlo 100 feet away, I'm afraid the answer is: you can't.

Comment: If your question is: how can I capture license plates from 30ft away, then please check [the earlier question and answer on that topic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/128801/9161) and feel free to [edit] your question to ask about points that were not addressed in the linked question.